# {sin,cos}(arctan(x)) vs. x / (x^2 + y^2)

Tags: python, numpy

I have to compute `{sin, cos}(arctan2(x))` on a regular basis. These expressions have much cheaper equivalents, namely

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

a, b = np.random.rand(2)

print(np.cos(np.arctan2(b, a)))
print(a / np.sqrt(a ** 2 + b ** 2))
# or a / np.hypot(a, b)
print()
print(np.sin(np.arctan2(b, a)))
print(b / np.hypot(a, b))
```

```
0.6087819565465009
0.6087819565465009

0.7933375885355579
0.793337588535558
```

Unfortunately, for the important border case `a == b == 0.0`, the alternative yields and error and gives `nan`. I'd like to avoid both.

Is there a specialized function that computes `{sin, cos}(arctan2(x))` or perhaps another more appropriate expression? Like the above, it needs to work for scalar and vector inputs.

Comment: `np.arctan2(0, 0)` returns 0.  That is a common convention, but it is not mathematically correct (`nan` would make more sense).  With that convention, `cos(arctan2(0, 0))` gives 1, and `sin(arctan2(0, 0))` gives 0.   Does that mean you expect, with `a` and `b` both 0,  `a / hypot(a, b)` to be 1, and `b / hypot(a, b)` to be 0?

Comment: Yeah that's right. I'm reading that `arctan2(0, 0) == 0` is really just a (common) implentation detail. I should perhaps assume it to be NaN and use `np.nan_to_num`.

Answer (score 1):

One possible trick to get around this issue is to just add a small epsilon to the values when you are dividing by zero.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)

a = np.random.rand(10)
b = np.random.rand(10)

a[0] = 0
b[0] = 0

eps = 1e-9

p1 = np.cos(np.arctan2(b, a))
p2 = (a+eps) / ((np.sqrt(a ** 2 + b ** 2))+eps)

print(np.allclose(p1, p2))

p1 = np.sin(np.arctan2(b, a))
p2 = b / (np.hypot(a, b)+eps)

print(np.allclose(p1, p2))
```

Comment: This does not work for values != 0, right?

Comment: It should. For any value !=0, the effect of adding that eps should be minimal so that it shouldn't really effect the values that much. In the example given, both the comparisons gives `True` even though there are non zero values in there.